# Running built in javascript with UIWebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

Currently, I am developing an application which can receive, from a call to a webservice, a string which represents an HTML file.  This string will then be loaded into a UIWebView and displayed to the user.  The problem I'm seeing is the UIWebView is not executing javascript/jquery that would normally fire when the form loads (in this instance doing things like hiding portions of the form until certain radiobuttons are selected).

```
-(id) initWithString:(NSString *)HTML{
{
    _html = HTML;
    _htmlView = [[UIWevView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [_htmlView setDelegate:self]
    [_htmlView loadHTMLString:_html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:_htmlView];
    return self;
}
```

Any insight on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching around and comparing the html I got in vs some other files that actually did work with javascript, I noticed that the service we used to pull the files down was translating symbols in the html to their escaped formats (& == &amp for example).  Once I parsed these out, the code ran fine and javascript fired normally.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

Refer [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Is this required even for the $(document).ready event?  I've tried running that method several ways, including just invoking the method my ready function calls, and I still get the same results